# Can I disable Subversion's locking features?

Tags: svn

My team has no reason to use the feature, but some of the GUI tools place the revert and lock button very close together and we end up with accidental locks.

We are running the distro `svn` package, v1.6, on CentOS 5.x and 6.x.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.locking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't disable locking in Subversion, but you can at least prevent chaos.

Quote from your link

> In particular, the pre-lock and pre-unlock hooks allow administrators to decide when lock creation and lock releases are allowed to happen.

i.e you can **disable any creation of locks** in [hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-lock.html).

In worse case locks can be removed (by cron?) in repository regularly (`svnadmin lslocks|rmlocks`)